# attendance table query Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I reconsidered my question based on previous comments

here is my attendance sqlite table

table_1

```
day    name    hours    
1      Jack    2
1      Jane    2
1      Jane    4
2      Jane    2
2      John    2
3      John    4
3      Jane    6
```

I would like to reset to 0 all rows 'hours' when name that has reached 6 hours  using a sub query :

```
c.execute('UPDATE table_1 SET hours = 0 WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table_1 WHERE hours = 6')
```

however it does not set to 0 the entire row hours for jane name, but only the one with 6 hours, not sure I can use such subquery - thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Sadly, this question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. Enjoy the [tour] to learn more about it. Feel free to ask a question when you run into a specific problem or post on Code Review to get opinions on **running** code

Comment: I think Breeze's comment is correct, but a bit vague. The problem is that this question is pretty broad - SO isn't the right place for "here's what I'm thinking, is it okay?" questions. It would be better to make a concrete attempt at your solution, then come back for *specific* help if you can't get it to work.

Comment: thanks , I reconsidered my question step by step.